# Ifconfig command doesn't show wifi adapter

Tags: networking, macos, command-line, network-adapter

I have a little problem. I have 2 wifi adapters at home (1 TP-link T2U AC600 plus and a TP-link T4U AC1300),

I installed the driver and have acces to the internet. So I think the configuration went well.

The problem is, when I enter the `Ifconfig` command on my macbook it doesn't recognize the adapter. I found this page: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/603506/what-are-these-ifconfig-interfaces-on-macos which tells me that `en1, en2, en3 and en4` are the thunderbolt names. I use a usb 3 to usb-c adapter to connect my wifi adapter to my laptop.

If I run the `ifconfig` command with the internal wifi card off and my wifi adapter on, this is the output:

```
  `en0: flags=8923<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
        ether - 
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
        status: inactive
    
    en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
        ether - 
        media: autoselect <full-duplex>
        status: inactive
    
    en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
        ether - 
        media: autoselect <full-duplex>
        status: inactive
    
    en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
        ether - 
        media: autoselect <full-duplex>
        status: inactive
    
    en4: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
        ether - 
        media: autoselect <full-duplex>
        status: inactive`
```

So this tells me that my wifi adapter isn't recognized. Does anyone have a idea how to fix this?

Comment: If I understand right, you use an adapter "usb 3 to usb-c" and connect the wifi adapter via usb-c. Perhaps the problem is with this adapter.

Comment: Hi Harrymc, thanks for the reply! I use a Hyperdrive usb-c hub to convert usb 3 ports to usb-c. My laptop only has usb-c ports. (https://www.hypershop.com/collections/usb-c-hubs/products/hyperdrive-power-9-in-1-usb-c-hub-for-mac-pc-android-usb-c-devices?variant=20087181443134)